# leetcode add two numbers loop

Tags: python, linked-list

I am working on LeetCode problem [2. Add Two Numbers](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/):

> You are given two **non-empty** linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in **reverse order**, and each of their nodes contains a single digit. Add the two numbers and return the sum as a linked list.
>
> You may assume the two numbers do not contain any leading zero, except the number 0 itself.

I am failing one of the test cases where l1 = [9,9,9,9,9,9,9] and l2 = [9,9,9,9]. I am outputting [8,9,9,9,9,1] and the correct output is [8,9,9,9,0,0,0,1]. My python code is posted below. I'm pretty sure my first while loop (`l1 and l2`) is working fine. I can't figure out what in the second loop (`while l1`) I need to change to get the correct output.

```
if l1 == [0] and l2 == [0]:
    return ListNode()
if l1 == [0]:
    return l2
if l2 == [0]:
    return l1

carry = False
sum_num = ListNode()
head = sum_num

while l1 and l2:
    temp = l1.val + l2.val
    if carry:
        temp += 1
        carry = False
    if temp >= 10:
        carry = True
        sum_num.val = temp % 10
    if temp < 10: #changed these from an if because not triggering correctly because double if
        sum_num.val = temp
    l1 = l1.next
    l2 = l2.next
    if not l1 or not l2:
        break
    sum_num.next = ListNode()
    sum_num = sum_num.next

while l1:
    temp2 = l1.val
    if carry:
        temp2 += 1
        carry = False
    if temp2 >= 10:
        carry = True
        sum_num.val = temp % 10
    if temp2 < 10:
        sum_num.val = temp
    l1 = l1.next
    if not l1:
        break
    sum_num.next = ListNode()
    sum_num = sum_num.next

while l2:
    temp3 = l2.data
    if carry:
        temp3 += 1
        carry = False
    if temp3 >= 10:
        carry = True
        sum_num.val = temp % 10
    if temp3 < 10:
        sum_num.val = temp
    l2 = l2.next
    if not l2:
        break
    sum_num.next = ListNode()
    sum_num = sum_num.next

if carry:
    sum_num.val = 1

return head
```

Comment: Please edit your question and copy-paste your code into a codebox, instead of a screenshot. It's easier for _us_ to help if _we_ can copy-paste your code, which we can't do from an image.

Comment: Have you tried writing the code in an IDE and setting breakpoints or adding print statements to see where it goes wrong? Also, what "first" loop are you referring to?

Comment: Looks to me like you're stopping your first loop at the end of the shorter number, instead of the longer number.

Comment: I'd use itertools.zip_longest with fillvalue=0

Answer (score 0):

Two problems:

- You have references to `temp` instead of `temp2` and `temp3` in your second and third loop, which obviously will lead to wrong results.
- When all the loops have been done, and there is a carry, you *overwrite* the value of the last added node with a 1. This is wrong. You need a new node for storing the carry.

Some other remarks:

- I would find the code less confusing if you would only create a node when you already have the value for it ready. Then you can call `ListNode(temp)` or something -- passing the value it needs. This way you also can do away with the conditional break in your loops.
- You have three loops with code repetition. Avoid this repetition and let your first loop continue while either of the list references is not None. So change the while condition to an OR and let the body of the loop deal with the case where a list reference might be None.
- If you make `carry` an integer instead of a boolean, it is easier to work with: you can just add the carry and calculate its new value by dividing `temp` by 10.
- It is not really necessary to deal with the special cases where a list may be [0]. It is true that this may give some speed benefit for those particular cases, but I would leave them out.

Here is your code updated with the above remarks:

```
carry = 0  # Integer instead of boolean -- easier to work with here
sum_num = None  # Don't create a node yet
head = None

while l1 or l2:  # Changed condition to avoid code repetition in 2 more loops
    temp = carry  # Since carry is an int, we can just add this 0 or 1.
    if l1:  # Deal gracefully with a None
        temp += l1.val
        l1 = l1.next
    if l2:
        temp += l2.val
        l2 = l2.next
    carry = temp // 10  # Simple way to set the new carry
    new_node = ListNode(temp % 10)  # Create node now that you know the value
    if head: 
        sum_num.next = new_node
    else:  # First time
        head = new_node
    sum_num = new_node

# No code repetition here. Just one more thing to do:
if carry:
    sum_num.next = ListNode(1)

return head
```